# mysqli_fetch_row syntax confusion

Tags: php, syntax, mysqli, syntax-error

I'm new to PHP and I copied this code;

```
$sql = "SELECT userID, username, password, first_name FROM users WHERE email='$e' AND activated='1' LIMIT 1";
        $query = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
        $row = mysqli_fetch_row($query);
        $db_id = $row[0];
        $db_username = $row[1];
        $db_pass_str = $row[2];
        $db_firstname = $row[3];
```

But it's just not working... And here's what my table looks like;

```
UserID -- username -- firstname -- lastname --  email  --------- password  

1   --    CJ_65 --    Craig -----  Johnson  --  CJ@email.com  -- passwordd
```

Can anybody help me out?

Comment: What error is being thrown? On that $query statement, add in "or die(mysql_error())" at the end of it.

Comment: no error is being thrown per-se, but, im using this to set up my sessions and my session data seems to be mixed up... :/

Comment: So it's actually working but the output is not correct?

Comment: yeah...is my syntax correct?

Comment: In $query = mysqli_query($connection, $sql); take out the $connection part and just leave it as: $query = mysqli_query($sql); and run that for me.

Comment: Oh please, stop storing password in plain text; use a [strong password hashing algorithm](http://php.net/password).

Comment: Cut OP some slack, they copied the code and are learning sql statements. This will just confuse them. I agree with using a hash but that isn't the prevalent issue here.

Comment: i just put a false password here for time and space's sake... @BuddhistBeast, strangely enough........ it works! O.o. I'll have to inspect my whole code and see what silly mistake I made. I'm really new to this

Comment: just explain what is wrong and what you want so others can help u. there is no question in your post except "can anyone help me" of course not unless we know what help you want.

Comment: thats good, but the OP should explain, so the question could be constructive and helpful to community

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Be cautious on the correct implementation being used with your SQL statements. All you need to do is  take out the $connection part of your $query.. in other words.. go from this:

```
$query = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
```

to this:

```
$query = mysqli_query($sql);
```

To learn the documentation a little better check this manual [out](http://www.php.net/mysqli_query). MySQl is a big step to be taking in the learning process of web development but the only way to get better is to keep practicing it and looking up the correct syntax/inputs for the the majority of the statements. You got this :)

Comment: Of course! Don't forget to click the arrow up as well :) Good luck with your MySQL journey, you'll do just fine!

Answer (score -1):

Since you outlined that you're new to PHP, I'd suggest learning prepared statements over MySQLi non-prepared statements. PDO is fairly simple to use:

```
<?
    // Database connection details
    $connection = new PDO("mysql:host=hostNameHere; dbname=databaseNameHere", "usernameHere", "passwordHere");

    // Database query
    $stmt = $connection->prepare("
        SELECT userID, username, password, first_name 
        FROM users 
        WHERE email = ? 
        AND activated = ? 
        LIMIT 1
    ");
    $stmt->execute(array($emailValue, $activatedValue));
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
?>
```